# How to compile the dates when media files were created and modified before back-up?

Tags: file-management, windows, file-transfer

How to automatically compile and index the following Windows properties for a batch of photo and video files (grouped across different folders per event) into one nice text-based document or table file? When a photo or video was shot is absolutely important to any creator and needs to be preserved against being overwritten by back-up and editing dates inserted by Windows.

- Date created
- Date modified
- Date last accessed

The problem is that whenever I back up photo and video files,

1. the date created is changed if I **copy** them to the back-up drive, or
2. the original files can't be retained on the source drive if I **cut and paste** them to a back-up drive.

I need something that aggregates these Windows properties into one document automatically, instead of manually doing it myself.

Comment: This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/): why are you trying to do this with Windows properties rather than the EXIF metadata embedded in the file itself? (and stepping back a bit, why are you not using Lightroom/Darktable/etc to do this for you)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it deal with files meta information and not in photographic aspect.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I think this is about the photographic aspect, as the OP is trying to effectively maintain their photo catalog. I still think it's the wrong approach though!

Comment: @PhilipKendall, for me this is file management based on the files meta information. Replace word "photo" with "video" and the OP should ask the question in totally different site. SuperUser is much more appropriate.

Comment: Encode the creation date in the filename?

Comment: How do I see a `.mts` (mp4) file's  EXIF metadata? I have never used EXIF before or know what it is. This question is highly relevant to photography because the need to catalog and archive collections with thousands of photos is wildly obvious, pre- vs post-processing. SuperUser doesn't let me post. And great, the question isn't about EXIF, it's about AGGREGATING thousands of photos' EXIF data automatically from any given Windows folder, or a wide assembly of Windows folders on a PC

Answer (score 1):

On non-Microsoft filesystems, "Date created" in file systems has always meant "date the file was added to the file system it is sitting on", so it is set to the time the file is copied, and is not an absolute date that never changes. On Microsoft file systems, it depends if the file is copied to the file system (from the same or another FS) (new time stamp) or moved (also from the same or another FS) (time stamp is kept)(*). So that explain Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V which is a copy, and Ctrl-X/Ctrl-V which is a move. But not all Microsoft FS support it.

If you want to get the "shooting date", then it is part of the image EXIF metadata data:

- `DateTimeOriginal` (0x9003)
- `DateTimeDigitized` (0x9004)

(usually identical on picture from cameras)

"Date of last access" is of little value/low trust because it requires writing back to the file system. So 1) it's not good for performance, 2) it's not good for media wear (SSD...) and 3) it may even bee not possible (read-only file system, because of media type, or access privileges). Modern filesystem have developed various strategies to mitigate this, but most of these rely on the idea that access time isn't critical (for instance, on the NTFS file system, it is accurate to **a day** (*), and may not be updated for over an hour). In addition, many things change it, even when not needed (thumbnails, etc...).

So you are left with the modification date(**), but this is taken care of by proper use of file utilities. Copying/moving a file to another drive shouldn't change this. EXIF data also has a field for this, `DateTime` (reported as `ModifyDate` by `exiftool`)(0x0132)

You can get these dates with various utilities, the `exiftool` command line utility being quite popular:

```
> exiftool -dateTimeOriginal -modifydate SomePhoto.jpg 
Date/Time Original              : 2023:03:06 16:00:12
Modify Date                     : 2023:03:08 23:41:34
```

Exiftool has extensive formatting abilities, so you can generate a line with all the info you need for each file, see examples [here](https://exiftool.org/examples.html). For instance to create a CSV for the files shoot date and last modification date (Unix syntax, quoting is likely different on Windows):

```
exiftool -p '"$filename";"$dateTimeOriginal";"$modifydate"' *.JPG > photos.csv
```

yields:

```
"IMG_9737.JPG";"2023:03:06 16:00:12";"2023:03:06 16:00:12"
"IMG_9739.JPG";"2023:03:07 13:59:34";"2023:03:07 13:59:34"
"IMG_9740.JPG";"2023:03:07 13:59:50";"2023:03:07 13:59:50"
"IMG_9741.JPG";"2023:03:07 13:59:50";"2023:03:07 13:59:50"
"IMG_9743.JPG";"2023:03:07 14:00:07";"2023:03:07 14:00:07"
"Edited1.JPG";"2023:03:06 16:00:12";"2023:03:08 23:41:34"
"Edited2.JPG";"2023:03:06 16:00:12";"2023:03:07 14:08:15"
```

Exiftool also supports video (at least it can show the same information from .MOV out of my Canon camera).

(*) Some good background information [here](https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/299648) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times)

(**) This date misses an important information: it is not changed if a file is renamed, so a backup may overlook the change. Unix file systems (OSX, Linux) also have a "change date" to support this.

Comment: "Date created" is NOT "the date the file was added to the file system it is sitting on" or "the time the file is copied". I know because I just **cut and pasted** a file to an external HDD last night and the pasted file retained the Creation Date as if it were the original, which was deleted at source upon cutting and pasting.  The Creation Date only changes during file transfer when you **copy and paste** to a new system or drive, which is the situation you just described.

Comment: **Date modified**, on the other hand, like what you say, definitely seems to be static for both when you're copy pasting or cut pasting. However, it rarely corresponds to creation date, often being 10 mins after a video file's creation date, I guess meaning that Date Modified is when the file finished recording versus when you started recording.

Comment: `exiftool` seems to do the job from your output, but still needs a next step to paste into a `csv` notepad. Would like to know of similar alternatives, preferably no download and install of obscure software.

Comment: The MS-DOS screen where `exiftool` resides can hardly accommodate 100 entries of file data (need for 500+ media files). Alot of manual labor would have to follow.

Comment: OK, the behavior of Microsoft is a bit different, see [here](https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/299648). But it still means that it can change... The last `exiftool` example ( with ` photos.csv` at the end) creates the CSV file directly. And it is **and example** it can be enhance to create a CSV with a whole disk of photos if necessary.

Comment: With all due respect, `exiftool` is not "obscure software"; it is absolutely 100% the standard tool for any kind of scripted management of photo metadata.